# Get rid of unicode decimal charater

Tags: python, unicode, tuples, python-3.6, python-unicode

I have a huge file which looks like this :

```
6814;gymnocéphale;185;151;49
6815;gymnodonte;83;330;0
6816;gymnosome;287;105;42
6817;hà mã;69;305;0
6818;h&#7843;i âu;81;294;0
6819;h&#7843;i c&#7849;u;64;338;0
6820;h&#7843;i y&#7871;n;62;269;0
6848;histiophore;57;262;0
6849;hiverneur;56;248;0
6850;h&#7893mang;54;298;0
6851;holobranche;97;329;0
6852;hoplopode;65;296;0
6853;h&#432&#417u cao c&#7893;152;298;0
6854;huy&#7873n &#273;&#7873;62;324;0
6855;hyalosome;73;371;0
6883;jumarre;83;295;0
6884;kéc;86;326;0
6885;k&#7873;n k&#7873;n;73;303;0
6886;khoang;64;323;0
6887;kh&#432;&#7899;u;62;325;0
```

As you can see the file contains some unicode decimal, I would like to replace all of them with their latin character before using the file. Even opening it with the utf-8 encoding, the errors are not suppress.

do you know a way to do it. I want to create a dictionary and retrieve the Numbers at index 2.

```
for  : 6883;jumarre;83;295;0;   => i have 83
for : 6887;kh&#432;&#7899;u;62;325;0   => i have &#7899 => which is false , i should have 62
```

```
with codecs.open('JeuxdeMotsPolarise_test.txt', 'r', 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as text_file:
    text_file =(text_file.read())
    #print(text_file)

dico_lexique =  ({i.split(";")[1]:i.split(";")[2:]for i in text_file.split("\n") if i})
```

This is the result given with trying @serge proposition, but it leaves blank spaces between lines.

```
6814;gymnocéphale;185;151;49

6815;gymnodonte;83;330;0

6816;gymnosome;287;105;42

6817;hà mã;69;305;0

6818;hi âu;81;294;0

6819;hi cu;64;338;0

6820;hi yn;62;269;0

6848;histiophore;57;262;0

6849;hiverneur;56;248;0

6850;h mang;54;298;0

6851;holobranche;97;329;0

6852;hoplopode;65;296;0

6853;hu cao c;152;298;0

6854;huyn ;62;324;0

6855;hyalosome;73;371;0

6883;jumarre;83;295;0

6884;kéc;86;326;0

6885;kn kn;73;303;0

6886;khoang;64;323;0

6887;khu;62;325;0
```

Edit : I redownload the original file and the error of missing ";" was corrected.

for example:

=> 6850;hổ mang;54;298;0 (that is how is appeared in the now update file)

Thank you everybody

Comment: The file doesn't contain any "unicode decimal". It's just US-ASCII text with some escape sequences. Unicode is what you read right now - StackOverflow uses Unicode internally (like all .NET applications) and produces UTF8 text, which is why I can write αυτό εδώ and know there won't be any encoding issue or escape sequences, either in the rendered text or the source

Comment: it's not ASCII, but probably `CP-1252` or some other codepage. Else the `é` in `gymnocéphale` would be gone too. The text file itself might be saved in UTF8 if the conversion was done somewhere further upstream

Comment: @MaartenFabré you're right. In any case, trying to replace Unicode text in non-Unicode text will fail, simply because the characters aren't there.

Comment: The real solution would be to fix the code that produced this file and have it create real UTF8 files. The workaround is to decode the text first before trying to perform any manipulations. How was this text produced?

Comment: @MaartenFabré , @ Panagiotis thank you! but how can i solve the problem any idea ?

Comment: @kely789456123 how was this produced in the first place? Fix that code.

Comment: It is french lexicon generated by a plateform which the code is not accessible. So i just export the file to use it to construct sentiment classifier. I  can try to contact the head of the site to explain the situation so that he ru n his script again.

Comment: Export it *how*, using which language? Python? C? Something else? What are those sequences supposed to mean? Googling for `&#432;` returns ư, definitely not a French character.

Comment: there is a link is the website on which you click and it automatically download the file on your computer, i think it was developed in python.

Comment: so to explain, it is aninteractive website where people rate words and it was developed for french. It because i have the issue with encoding, i noticed there are some words which are not french words. I will try to go deep in the website to see why there are some non french words.

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking a part of the problem, but have you thought about `line.split(";")[-3]` ?

Comment: @kely789456123 again, UTF8 is what you see here. UTF8 doesn't use escape sequences. Those sequences *could* be [HTML entities](ISO-8859-1) *BUT* they are outside the ISO-8859-1 range. That range already contains French characters anyway. Googling for those sequences returns *Vietnamese* characters

Comment: For example,  `kh&#432;&#7899;u` is probably Khướu

Comment: yes, i went to the original file and i reloaded again, since i am looking at the score  if can retrieve  them it will be enough but maybe  i will have to get rid of all the line with  those sequences since I will work with french material. Thank you again.

Comment: @kely789456123 use `html.unescape` on each line. It will replace the escape sequences with the appropriate characters, which in this case are Vietnamese

Comment: ok. I will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@PanagiotisKanavos has correctly guessed that `html.unescape` was able to replace the xml char reference with their unicode character. The hard part is that some refs are correctly ended with their terminating semicolon (`;`) while others are not. And in that latter case, if one entity if followed with a semicolon **separator**, the separator will be eaten by the convertion, shifting the following fields.

So the only reliable way is to:

1. process the file line by line as as CSV file with `;` delimiter
2. eventually contatenate the middle field from the second to the fourth starting form the end
3. unescape that middle field

If you want to convert the file, you could do:

```
with open('file.csv') as fd, open('fixed.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter=';')
    wr = csv.writer(fdout, delimiter=';')
    for row in rd:
        if len(row)> 5:
            row[1] = ';'.join(row[1:len(row)-3])
            del row[2:len(row)-3]
        row[1] = html.unescape(row[1])
        wr.writerow(row)
```

If you only want to build a mapping from field 0 to field 2:

```
values = {}
with open('file.csv') as fd:
    rd = csv.reader(fd, delimiter=';')
    for row in rd:
        values[field[0]] = field[-3]
```

Comment: The script that generated that file is (unintentionally) evil. Using text qualifiers would avoid the parsing issues.

Comment: @thank you for the solution but the generated file is full of empty blank , how can I suppress them  when filling the second file ?

Comment: @kely789456123, `endline=''` should avoid blank lines in output csv.

Answer (score 1):

This text isn't UTF8 or Unicode in general. It's [HTML-encoded text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML), most likely Vietnamese. Those escape sequences correspond to Vietnamese characters, for example `&#432` is ư - in fact, I just typed the edit sequence in the SO edit box and the correct character appeared. `&#7899;` is ớ.

Copying the entire text outside a code block produces

6814;gymnocéphale;185;151;49

6815;gymnodonte;83;330;0

6816;gymnosome;287;105;42

6817;hà mã;69;305;0

6818;hải âu;81;294;0

6819;hải cẩu;64;338;0

6820;hải yến;62;269;0

6848;histiophore;57;262;0

6849;hiverneur;56;248;0

6850;h&#7893mang;54;298;0

6851;holobranche;97;329;0

6852;hoplopode;65;296;0

6853;h&#432&#417u cao cổ152;298;0

6854;huy&#7873n đề62;324;0

6855;hyalosome;73;371;0

6883;jumarre;83;295;0

6884;kéc;86;326;0

6885;kền kền;73;303;0

6886;khoang;64;323;0

6887;khướu;62;325;0

Googling for Họ Khướu returns [this Wikipedia page about Họ Khướu](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%E1%BB%8D_Kh%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Bu).

I think it's safe to assume this is HTML-encoded Vietnamese text. To convert it to Unicode you can use [html.unescape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html) :

```
import html
line='6887;kh&#432;&#7899;u;62;325;0'
properLine=html.unescape(line)
```

**UPDATE**

The text posted above is just the original text with an extra newline per page. It's SO's markdown renderer that converts the escape sequences to the corresponding glyphs.

The funny thing is that this line :

```
6853;h&#432&#417u cao c&#7893;152;298;0
```

Can't be rendered because the HTML entities aren't properly terminated. `html.unescape` on the other hand *will* convert the characters. Clearly, `html.unescape` is far more forgiving than SO's markdown renderer.

Either of these lines :

```
html.unescape('6853;h&#432;&#417;u cao c&#7893;152;298;0')
html.unescape('6853;h&#432&#417u cao c&#7893;152;298;0')
```

Returns :

```
6853;h\u01b0\u01a1u cao c\u1ed5152;298;0
```

Comment: `html.unescape('6853;h&#432&#417u cao c&#7893;152;298;0')` produces the wrong result.

Comment: @daxim I'll raise the bug with the SO team. You can *clearly* see in the other lines what those characters generate. Separating the lines by a newline renders the text correctly. If you want to downvote I'll try to find whoever writes the markdown renderer.

Comment: @daxim since you have enough rep you can hit `edit` and check that the text in this answer is the *same* as the question's, with extra newlines to avoid the rendering problem

Comment: This has nothing to do with markdown. Your proposed solution kills a needed semicolon in input line 13.

Comment: @daxim and yet, my solution produces legible text. It fixes the bad assumption that the data is somehow related to UTF8. What does *yours* produce?

Comment: @daxim and yes, it is about the rendered. Hit `edit` to prove to yourself that I just copied the OP's text

Comment: "legible text" is not what I was critiquing. Again, this has nothing to do with Markdown or how SO renders something. The problem is that due to the missing semicolon, you broke the next step: CSV parsing. You need to programmatically put back the missing semicolon. `html.unescape` alone is not a complete solution.

Comment: @daxim updated with the Python code and results that show the difference between `html.unescape` and SO' markdown renderer. And no, I didn't break the next step. If the data is lost, splitting lines becomes arbitrary

Comment: @daxim in any case, this is a Python question. Serge posted a Python answer. Can you post a *Python* answer? BTW the results you posted mix 5 and 6-column rows.

Answer (score 0):

Repair the file first before you load it into a CSV parser.

Assuming Maarten in the comments is right, change the encoding:

```
iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 < JeuxdeMotsPolarise_test.txt > JeuxdeMotsPolarise_test.utf8.txt
```

Then replace the escapes with proper characters.

```
perl -C -i -lpe'
    s/&#([0-9]+);?/chr $1/eg;       # replace entities
    s/;?(\d+;\d+;\d+)$/;$1/;        # put back semicolon
                                    # if it was consumed accidentally
' JeuxdeMotsPolarise_test.utf8.txt
```

Contents of `JeuxdeMotsPolarise_test.utf8.txt` after running the substitutions:

```
6814;gymnocéphale;185;151;49
6815;gymnodonte;83;330;0
6816;gymnosome;287;105;42
6817;hà mã;69;305;0
6818;hải âu;81;294;0
6819;hải cẩu;64;338;0
6820;hải yến;62;269;0
6848;histiophore;57;262;0
6849;hiverneur;56;248;0
6850;hổmang;54;298;0
6851;holobranche;97;329;0
6852;hoplopode;65;296;0
6853;hươu cao cổ;152;298;0
6854;huyền đề;62;324;0
6855;hyalosome;73;371;0
6883;jumarre;83;295;0
6884;kéc;86;326;0
6885;kền kền;73;303;0
6886;khoang;64;323;0
6887;khướu;62;325;0
```

Comment: You assume the file is broken. What if it's Vietnamese instead of French?

Comment: Your comment does not really make sense. OP already said the file is broken. The language is not relevant to the code I posted, either.

Comment: Google the escape sequences. You'll see they are HTML escape sequences for *Vietnamese* characters.  The OP *assumes* the file is UTF8 and that it's broken. It's definitely *not* UTF*, so why assume it's broken?

Comment: If you google for `kh&#432;&#7899;u` for example you'll get [this Wikipedia page about Họ Khướu](https://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%E1%BB%8D_Kh%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Bu)

Comment: You're one out of 4 major participants in this thread, but the only one misunderstanding the problem. Once again: the file is not really usable as is and needs at least one extra step of decoding (entities). And once again: the natural language is not relevant, the program works on the Unicode level. Just run my code and inspect the changed file, the result should be quite enlightening. PS: You could have saved us all some time by pointing out the bug with the semicolons in a straight-forward manner.

Comment: Check [Serge's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56425194/134204). It doesn't mangle the data *and* manages to read the file as CSV. Changing the codepage won't fix anything anyway, but it won't mangle the text the way a replacement would

Comment: I focused on the eye-popping problem first - UTF8 when there's no UTF8 in sight. I took the time to find out what that text was but had to rush to post an answer as some answers will result in data loss. I hadn't even noticed the CSV problem that appears *after* unescaping

Comment: You cannot repair the file without parsing it as CSV, because some semicolons (`;`) are HTML reference terminators, while others are the csv delimiters. And not all HTML references are terminated...

Comment: Serge, you are incorrect. Not with what you said directly, but with the assumption. Please run my code and verify that it produces the correct result. You should do that before you write up a critique.

Comment: @daxim this is a Python question and you posted non-Python code. The first call won't do anything, it will produce the strings we see in this question right now. SO pages use UTF8. The second may or may not work. You can post a sample of the output instead of saying others got it wrong. What does the *last* line look like after running your code?

Comment: My answer is correct and can be independently verified by anyone. You're simply wrong about that the first call doesn't do anything. Output amended, although it's not my obligation.

Comment: @daxim different rows have different column numbers. The OP's data has 5 columns while these results have 5 or 6 columns. For example `6854;huyền đề;62;324;0` has 5 rows while `6855;hyalosome;7;3;371;0` has *6* rows.

Comment: @daxim in any case, can you post a *Python* answer? The codepage conversion isn't needed. The regex substitutions can be rewritten in Python. Without counting columns though, I suspect the easiest way to fix this would be to tread everything between then 1st and the last 3 numeric columns as a single text field and call `html.unescape` on it